# How do I get the count of the selected checkboxes and display the count in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, typescript, dropdownbox

I need help displaying the count of a list of checkboxes into the value of a dropdown box. Where do I need to get my count from? The checkboxes are being passed dynamically as an array.

***Here is my current code.***

**DropDownBox Component**

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" [autoClose]="false">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle{{title}}`(need to display the count here)`
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <input type="text" placeholder="{{searchPlaceholder}}" class="searchBox" />
             <div *ngFor="let data of datas">
                   <cst-checkbox [checkBoxValue] = "data" [ngModel]="data.selected"></cst-checkbox>
             </div> 
       </div> 
</div>
```

**Checkbox component**

```
<div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" value="{{checkBoxValue}}" />
     <label>{{checkBoxValue}}</label>     
</div>
```

*The checkbox component is `<cst-checkbox>` in the dropdown component.*

Answer (score 2):

You can create your Custom Pipe to get selected values only, by filtering them up

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'getSelcted',
    pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class GetSelectedPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[]): any {
        // take out only selected values
        return items.filter(item => item.selected === true);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
{{(datas: getSelcted)?.length || 0}}
```

> **Note:** Make sure `GetSelectedPipe` has been injected in `declarations` of AppModule's @NgModule `declartions` array.

Comment: I tried your above code. However i had the following error during runtime. Do you have any idea why?

dashboard:28 Error: Error: Unexpected value 'CSTMultiSelectComponent' exported by the module 'CSTModule'

Comment: Is there any other way to get the count of selectedCheckbox using the `@Input` or `@Output` method to pass to other html file?

Comment: It seems like you have messed up something with NgModule